# Do references, notes, and tables count towards journal word count restrictions?

Tags: journals, writing, paper-submission

I'm preparing a manuscript to be submitted to a journal, but I'm struggling with the language used regarding the word count for this specific journal:

> The ___________is a peer-reviewed publication. Articles
>   between 4000-7000 words (double spaced pages) including tables, notes
>   and references, are accepted for review. The Editors reserve the right
>   to return papers to authors where they exceed this word limit.

My confusion is, does this mean that references/notes/tables contribute to the word count of the manuscript for this particular journal?

Comment: In this case, the journal is explicit in saying that the word count "includes tables, notes, and references". I suppose the more interesting question is what is meant when there is no such explicit statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the references/notes/tables are to be included in the word count.

Comment: Cheers. Would this include the bibliography, or just in-text references do you think?

Comment: This would typically include the bibliography.